# Hadoop Streaming MapReduce slow finding files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop job that is taking a very long time to initialize when fed a large number of input files, and I'm not sure why.  The job will find all of the nodes and files within a few seconds, regardless of how many files are used, but takes significant time (minutes) to determine the number of splits if given 10,000 files. When I run the job as a different user, the job will determine the number of splits almost immediately.

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar -D 'mapreduce.job.name=...'
packageJobJar: [] [/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.11.0.jar] /tmp/streamjob4556879591438635545.jar tmpDir=null
17/08/07 22:01:40 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at jobtracker-dev.la.prod.factual.com/10.20.103.16:8032
...
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO security.TokenCache: Got dt for hdfs://dev; Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN....
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 674c65bbf0f779edc3e00a00c953b121f1988fe1]
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 10000
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /cs3/211/...
17/08/07 22:01:41 INFO net.NetworkTopology: Adding a new node: /cs3/210/...
...
<LONG PAUSE>
...
17/08/07 22:31:39 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:10000
```

This is not a lot of information, obviously, but does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Time taken depends of so many parameter, for starting you can check your cluster capacity, and yarn configuration specifically.
IF you have 10k splits that mean AM coordination with tasks will take significant amount of time , remember hadoop is built for big files processing not small {large number}files.
Do check your hdfs block size as well , and how much you are putting.
Make sure if you are distributed mode establish password less connection with your data nodes.
For specifically"**When I run the job as a different user, the job will determine the number of splits almost immediately.**" This is not HADOOP capacity issue, check your configuration properly. If possible use ambari to manage your cluster if you have enough budget to do so.